# How to check what package was updated using yum history?

Tags: linux, centos, yum

OK let's do a little experiment:
on a fresh installed CentOS, when I type `yum history list`, output is:

```
[user@machine ~]# yum history list
Loaded plugins: security
ID | Login user               | Date and time    | Action(s)      |  Altered
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 8 | root <root>              | 2017-03-02 09:42 | I, U           |   28   
 7 | root <root>              | 2017-03-02 09:41 | I, U           |    8   
 6 | root <root>              | 2016-01-30 10:48 | Update         |   10   
 5 | root <root>              | 2015-09-26 16:35 | Update         |    1  <
 4 | System <unset>           | 2015-07-14 21:28 | I, U           |   91 > 
 3 | System <unset>           | 2015-07-14 21:27 | Install        |    1   
 2 | System <unset>           | 2015-07-14 21:27 | Install        |    1   
 1 | System <unset>           | 2015-07-14 21:16 | Install        |  474   
 history list
```

now let's update vim using `yum update vim -y`, after that, `yum history list` produces this:

```
 [user@machine ~]# yum history list
 Loaded plugins: security
 ID     | Login user               | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 9 | root <root>              | 2017-07-28 18:08 | I, U           |    3   
 8 | root <root>              | 2017-03-02 09:42 | I, U           |   28   
 7 | root <root>              | 2017-03-02 09:41 | I, U           |    8   
 6 | root <root>              | 2016-01-30 10:48 | Update         |   10   
 5 | root <root>              | 2015-09-26 16:35 | Update         |    1  <
 4 | System <unset>           | 2015-07-14 21:28 | I, U           |   91 > 
 3 | System <unset>           | 2015-07-14 21:27 | Install        |    1   
 2 | System <unset>           | 2015-07-14 21:27 | Install        |    1   
 1 | System <unset>           | 2015-07-14 21:16 | Install        |  474
```

question is, how do I make sense of this output, provided that I am interested in seeing what package was updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With just that output you can't really make much sense of it. But if you look at [the documentation](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumHistory), you'll find that `yum history info` could provide you with more information what actually happened. It accepts the ID as a parameter.